# Julia: Declaring Types of Keyword Arguments with Variables

Tags: arrays, arguments, declaration, julia

Im trying to declare a type in my keyword argument of an array of Vectors that is variable dimensions choosen by the user at the start of the program. When I use a variable to declare the dimensions, terminal tells me the variable is unknown. This is not an issue in sub 0.4 Julia as multidimensional arrays can be declared with single dimensional arrays. Ive tried constants and they did not work for me either. Is there a way around this without dumping data to a text file and reading from function.

```
function dataDoer(len,preConns::Array{Array{Int64,1},(len)})
    println("do stuff here")
end


function main()
    local netDim = (2,2)
    local preConns::Array{Array{Int64,1},length(netDim)} = fill!(Array(Array{Int64,1},netDim),Int64[])

    dataDoer(length(netDim),preConns)
end

main()
```

ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: len not defined

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the [docs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/#implementation) for how Arrays are implemented, as they shed some light on what's going on here.

In `Array{T,N}`, the `N` doesn't refer to the *length* or *size* of an array, but it's **dimension**. `Array` can actually have variable length, with the option to `push!`, `append!`, and `splice!` elements in and out. To get the length of an array, you simply do `length(A)`. Hope that helps clarify!

Comment: If you look at my code, I am passing dimensions to the function not its size. I will edit my question to make this more clear. Even so, in 0.4 you need the proper dimensions to declare the type of an array, which makes me curious how effective declaring types for arrays were in 0.3.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make `len` a type parameter. (I've renamed it to `N` below, which is common practice for this kind of parameter.) Then you can do eg

```
function dataDoer{N}(preConns::Array{Array{Int64,1},N})
    println("do stuff here")
end
```

Note that `N` is no longer an argument of the function, but is inferred from the type of `preConns`.